# How to set Parsley.js global config

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsley.js, parsley

Most of the docs I found is not helping me as it seems to be outdated or I am doing something wrong.

```
$.fn.parsley.defaults = {} // not working
window.parsley.defaults = {} // not working
window.ParsleyConfig = {} // not working
```

Basically what I am trying to do is, I want the below given options to set globally and not repeat the same code for each form in my application:

```
$('#sign-in-form').parsley({
    successClass: "has-success",
    errorClass: "has-error",
    classHandler: function (el) {
      return el.$element.closest(".form-group");
    },
    errorsWrapper: "<span class='help-block'></span>",
    errorTemplate: "<span></span>"
  });
```

The above code is working (along with bootstrap)

Answer (score 1):

I hope to have improved [the doc](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#psly-usage-configuration) enough to answer your question.

Comment: The current version of the docs (Feb 2020) doesn't have any reference to how to set global configurations for use across a project. Has this feature been disabled?

Comment: For sure. Check the link in the response, section "option inheritance".